# Frames at the center of a page

Tags: jquery, frame, frames, filetree

I would need to put two separate frames at the center of a page that would exactly look like this (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RoIE.png)). The first frame (left) is where the file tree is displayed and the second frame is where the search results would appear. In that pic, I only put two separate divs with `overflow: scroll` style. The purpose why I am switching to frames is that I would not want my file tree to refresh and disappear whenever I click Submit button (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Y69.png)). Can anybody please help me? I would really appreciate it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFRAMEs inside those divs, if you wish.  This lets you put frames wherever you want.

One way which also works would be to stick with the current system, with everything on one page, and then use jQuery `$('#dir_area').load('thispage #dir_area', {dirname: 'dir_to_load'})` (something like that) to only load the part ("fragment") of the new page that you want to refresh.  See: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

I would store the last path in a session variable or cookie and then initialize my form every time I visit this page. I don't think using Iframe can help you with your problem.